# Android Wear Watchfaces: implement as a Service or as an Activity?

Tags: android, wear-os

I've had a lot of frustration trying to develop a Watch face for Android Wear.

First I got my watch face to function as I wanted, and used the default Service code to make sure it was working properly.

Then I wanted to change the UI. I made round and rect xml file, as well as the activity watch face xml that uses WatchViewStub. 
I realized that I made a mistake - this seems to only work with an Activity.

My question is - when would you use an Activity over a Service? The android developer docs say "Watch faces in Android Wear are implemented as services and packaged inside a wearable app"- https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html
I'm just confused as to whether I need to implement my watch face as a Service or as an Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your watch face as a `Service`.

To be more precise, you need to implement a subclass of `WatchFaceService`, which is subclass of `WallpaperService`.

You can find more information here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The only option for building a watch face using the [Watch Face APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html) is via a service.

You can override the [onApplyWindowInsets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html#onApplyWindowInsets(android.view.WindowInsets)) method and call [isRound()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html#isRound()) to determine if you are running on a round device, changing what you draw in `onDraw()` accordingly.